# Mail form not accepting the use of /

Tags: php, html, email

Im making a mail form and i need it to be able to use / in the form, so that it is possible to write a date like 11/10-2013.

I have the following $string_exp:

```
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z 0-9.'-,:ÆØÅæøå]+$/";
```

How can i add so that it is possible to use / in the form?

Comment: No, that did not work.

Comment: `$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z 0-9.'-,:/ÆØÅæøå]+$/";`

Comment: I tried that one allready, it just ends the string at the second / and the nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `/` in the char class, but since `/` is your regex delimiter, it'll have to be escaped:

```
"/^[...... \/ ....]$/"
           ^---escape
```